# Eclipse won't jump to declaration of namespaced classes

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel, namespaces, ide

how to configure my eclipse so it will (using `F3`) jump into declarations which are using namespaces?

i use:

```
use Input;
Input::get('sorting')
```

eclipse does not recognize the reference/declaration of `Input`, thus i see no autocomplete recommendations when typing `Input::g` nor `F3` works.

i'm using eclipse Version: 3.7.2 with php developer kit

**edit:** maybe it seems to be a `laravel-framework` related, since eclipse does jump into declarations such as

```
use Platise\ShopCore\Service\Cache\ICacheRepository;
```

but those declarations are actually a full path name to the class. maybe its a general eclipse problem that it cannot find namespaces which are shortened. just fyi, this declaration from laravels vendors doesnt work, too:

```
use Pagerfanta\Exception\OutOfRangeCurrentPageException;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a Laravel related issue, due to the class aliasing and Facades.

When I started I almost gave up for the framework because of this, but then I found a package that solves it, partially: [Laravel IDE Helper Generator](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Well.. it is not a definitive solution, but it works.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, i'll give a try and come back with the bounty if it will work

Comment: how did you set eclipse to use this `ide helper`? it seems to be for other IDEs only.

Comment: I'm using it with Eclipse. For this to work you need the Eclipse PHP plugin (PDT). Install Laravel IDE Helper, as mentioned in the plugin page, run `php artisan ide-helper:generate` and then refresh your project files in Eclipse.

Comment: i got this error when running the command: `[InvalidArgumentException]                                    
  There are no commands defined in the "ide-helper" namespace. `  btw i switched meanwhile to eclipse luna 4.4.1

Comment: version of PDT is `      PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.3.1.201409161013 org.eclipse.php.feature.group Eclipse.org`

Comment: Did you put the ServiceProvider in "app.php" as mentioned in the [Laravel IDE Helper GitHub page](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

Comment: @ulkas also, check if `php artisan` command shows `ide-helper` namespace.